# How can I use a class that is in another file?

Tags: c#, .net

I have my main class in a directory. Then I created a file in that directory, and put my other class into the file. If I need to use that class in my main class, how can I do that?

Comment: What IDE are you using to develop with?  Visual Studio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your *other* class has the same `namespace` as the `main` class, or *better* specify the namespace from other class in the main class `using` directives.

File 2. (Other Class)

```
namespace OtherClassNameSpace
{
    public class OtherClass
    {
    }
}
```

File 1. (main class)

```
using OtherClassNameSpace;

namespace MainClassNameSpace
{
     class MainClass
     {
           public OtherClass OtherClassTypeProperty {get; set;}
     }    

}
```